# How to compare multiple lines in one script and based on that, do something with the column in that row? In Bash

Tags: bash

So, I have a text file separated by tabs that looks like:

```
contig141    hit293    2939    71    293    alksjdflksdf
contig141    hit339    9393    71    302    kljdkfjsjdfksdf
contig124    hit993    9239    55    274    laksjdfkls
contig124    hit101    9333    66    287    aslkdjfalkdjsfkjlsdf
contig124    hit205    4856    123    301    ksdjflksjdfskldjfeiedfdwe
contig132    hit003    2290    58    290    jsdfishfoisodncklsn
contig133    hit100    1889    21    107    sijhfdshfdjhsdjkdfjf
```

For each contig, I want to subtract the 4th column from the 5th column, and compare the differences. For the contig with the largest difference, I would like to print the entire row to a new file. I'm thinking of a nested loop, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm thinking:

```
Loop over each row of the file. 
   set variable a = string in first column of the first row
   while: the string in the first column of the next row is equal to a, 
      take the difference of the 4th and 5th column
      compare the differences among all rows of that contig
      output the row with the greatest difference to a new file
```

So you would compare the differences between the 4th and 5th column for contig141, and output the line with the greatest difference. Repeat for contig124, etc. etc.

Comment: please update the question with the desired output (eg, for `config141` and `config124`); also show the code you've tried and the (wrong) results being generated by your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficient way to address this is with `awk` redirecting the output to a new file. In fact any time you start thinking "I need to do X with a field...", your first thought should be `awk`. (it is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing). You can do what you need with:

```
awk '{
    diff = $5-$4
    if (diff > config[$1]) { 
        config[$1] = diff
        rec[$1] = $0
    }
}
END { for(i in config) print rec[i] }' file > newfile
```

Above you simply calculate the difference between the 5th and 4th field saving in `diff`. Then check if that difference is the max for the array element of `config` index by the first field, and if so, update `config[$1] = diff` saving the max difference for the config, and save the record (line) as `rec[$1]` also indexed by the first field. Then using the `END` rule, you simply output the max record for each config.

**Example Use/Output**

Showing what would be redirected to the new file, you have

```
awk '{
>     diff = $5-$4
>     if (diff > config[$1]) {
>         config[$1] = diff
>         rec[$1] = $0
>     }
> }
> END { for(i in config) print rec[i] }' file
contig132    hit003    2290    58    290    jsdfishfoisodncklsn
contig141    hit339    9393    71    302    kljdkfjsjdfksdf
contig133    hit100    1889    21    107    sijhfdshfdjhsdjkdfjf
contig124    hit101    9333    66    287    aslkdjfalkdjsfkjlsdf
```

You can pipe to `sort` if you need the configs in sort order before redirecting to the new file, e.g.

```
$ awk '{
    diff = $5-$4
    if (diff > config[$1]) {
        config[$1] = diff
        rec[$1] = $0
    }
}
END { for(i in config) print rec[i] }' file | sort
contig124    hit101    9333    66    287    aslkdjfalkdjsfkjlsdf
contig132    hit003    2290    58    290    jsdfishfoisodncklsn
contig133    hit100    1889    21    107    sijhfdshfdjhsdjkdfjf
contig141    hit339    9393    71    302    kljdkfjsjdfksdf
```